# How to make a high amount of money on your computer fast and legally?

Tags: small-business

Hello Money StackExchange Community,

I hope this message finds you all well. I'm here to seek your advice and insights. I've seen how incredibly savvy many of you are when it comes to innovative income strategies, and that's exactly what I'm in need of.

I'm in a situation where I need to make a decent amount of money quite quickly, and I'm hoping to do this using my computer. I'm not after the usual "get-rich-quick" schemes or vague ideas; I need solid, step-by-step methods that I can start on immediately. Time is of the essence, and I'm ready to put in the work.

The ideal strategies would be those with a track record of quick monetization potential. I'm open to exploring new technologies, digital marketing, e-commerce—you name it, as long as it's legal and can start bringing in income soon.

Your wisdom and any pointers you can offer would be immensely appreciated!

Warm regards,

Bob

Comment: Look under the [scam] tag, there's a lot of options. Most (all?) are illegal, though.

Comment: A method of getting rich quickly that isn't a get-rich-quick scheme? Sounds like Homer Simpson: “After years of disappointment with get-rich-quick schemes, I know I'm gonna get rich with this scheme. And quick!”

Answer (score 2):

Someone online will sell a step to step guide for making a decent amount of money quickly. You just need to pay a few hundred or thousand bucks.

Sarcasm aside. Stop this idea and get a real job. There is no way you can legally make a large sum quickly online. Anyone claiming so is just after you money.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is contrary objectives.  If there was a lot of money that one can earn fast and easy on a computer, it would be easy enough to write an app/bot to repeat the task.  In fact I have done exactly that in the past.

It is by no means a lot of money, but it is fast.  Become a MTurk worker.  You can complete many tasks in a day or hour but the payment for each tasks tend to be a few cents.  One can earn a couple or three dollars per day if you dedicate only an hour of your time.  This is a great way to boost your investment account or pay off debt if you dedicate payments to that purpose.  If this kind of thing interest you, another resource is MyPoints which provide points that can be redeemed for different things of value like gift cards.

One way a person I know of that is doing quite well is delivering for Walmart grocery services.  She was making a lot more money than her traditional job and the hours are flexible.  One of the best things about doing deliveries is the pay is immediate, no waiting two or three weeks for the company's payroll cycle as in traditional jobs.